# Javascript, font color wont change a second time

Tags: javascript

I am making a simulation of a stock market i want to make it so when the market increases the numbers are green and lowering red. For some reason the color only stays green.

I have a list of bools to see if the market is climbing or not.

this is the java code:

```
var climbingIDK = new Array(true, true, true, true, true);

function update_stonks() {
    var stockValues = document.getElementsByClassName("value");
    for (let i = 0; i < stockValues.length; i++) {
        var incrementer = Math.round(Math.random()*11) /100;
        if (incrementer === 11){
            if(climbingIDK[i]){
                climbingIDK[i] = false;
            }
            else{
                climbingIDK[i] = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            var currentValue = parseInt(stockValues[i].innerHTML);
            if(climbingIDK[i]){
                stockValues[i].style.color = "#00ff00";
                stockValues[i].innerHTML = currentValue + incrementer;
            }
            else{
                if(currentValue - incrementer < 1){
                    stockValues[i].innerHTML = currentValue + incrementer;
                }
                else{
                    stockValues[i].style.color = "#ff0000";
                    stockValues[i].innerHTML = currentValue - incrementer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    setTimeout(update_stonks, 2000);
}

update_stonks();
```

this is my html:

Comment: Please use the `<>` button to create a [mre]. The HTML inside <body> is enough.

Comment: Where's the HTML?

Comment: You expect `Math.round(Math.random()*11) /100;` to equal `11`??? `console.log(Array.from({length: 100}, () => Math.round(Math.random()*11)/100))`

Comment: java !== javascript

Comment: if(climbingIDK[i]){} is always true (green) unless you change the first row.